# Which data structure should I use in which key changes after inserting <Key,Value> pair into the data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have a doubly linkedList in which I have indexes and Some values. The LinkedListNode structure is as below:

```
Class LinkedListNode
{
  int index;
  String Value;
}
```

If I change the index of one node in the linkedlist, the indexes of subsequent nodes in the linkedlist needs to be changed. To change the index of a LinkedListNode, I have to search nodes in the linked list based on indexes. Now, because indexes can change in the linked list nodes, I am confused on how should I do searching part on indexes because I can not simply use ArrayList and do this. So for that, I have used HashMap. As this HashMap have index as references, if any index gets changed in the linkedList nodes, it will get affected in the HashMap. But its not working as I want it to work i.e. find a node with given index in O(1) time. Any suggestions?

Objects being inserted into hashmap as keys are:

```
public class MyObject {
    int index;
    String str;
}
```

The driver class is:

```
public class HashMapTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<MyObject, String> map = new HashMap<MyObject, String>();

    MyObject mo = new MyObject();
    MyObject mo1 = new MyObject();

    mo.index = 1;

    map.put(mo, "abc");

    mo1.index =100;
    mo.index = 2;

    map.put(mo1, "pqr");

    mo1.index =200;

    System.out.println("value: " + map.get(mo));

    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(((MyObject)pairs.getKey()).index + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
}
```

Here `mo.index` changes from `1` to `2` and so when I output it, it gives `mo.index = 2`. Now how should I fetch `mo` object in `O(1)` time from the `HashMap`? Or is there another data structure which I can use to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Why not delete and reinsert an entry with a new key when you want to change the key?

Comment: @pkacprzak: Thank you. I thought of considering that option. But it won't work for me because, if one index is changing, subsequently many other indexes changes in my application. I can not delete all the elements and reinsert them each time when index changes. It would be too expensive in terms of time. Could you please suggest some other solution.

Comment: While a complete code sample is great, your code seems a bit too artificial at present - while we could just answer your question as stated, we may not be able to give you the best solution to your problem, as we don't have enough context regarding why you want to do this. See also - [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @Dukeling: I have a linkedList in which I have indexes. If I change the index of one node in the linkedlist, the indexes of subsequent nodes in the linkedlist needs to be changed. I have to search nodes in the linked list based on indexes. Now, because indexes can change in the linked list nodes, I am confused on how should I do searching part on indexes. For that I have used HashMap<MyObject,LinkedListNode>. But its not working as I want it to work i.e. find a node with given index in O(1) time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlienOnEarth Could you write something more about how indices change in your application?

Comment: There's no free lunch. If you want to handle changing keys you MUST rehash the object and reinsert it.  In the ideal case the time still approaches O(1) as long as the hashtable is big enough.

Comment: @pkacprzak: I have updated the question. I have explained the whole scenario.

Comment: @AlienOnEarth Do you always increment your keys by 1?

Comment: @pkacprzak: Yes. It can either increment by 1 or decrement by 1.

Comment: @AlienOnEarth and the last one, can you limit your keys to some range of integers? And is O(log n) complexity fine for you?

Comment: @pkacprzak: I can achieve o(log n) using TreeMap. I need some data structure for O(1). Also, indexes varies from 0 to n. But we can add n+1th node. So n also changes.

Comment: What you're asking probably isn't possible. If you can arbitrarily insert and delete items, and insertion affects the `index` values of all following nodes, then there's no way to maintain those values in O(1). If you inserted a new item at the head of the list, then you would *have to* update the index of every other node. I find it likely that you're asking the wrong question. What problem are you trying to solve with this data structure? There's probably a more workable solution.